# Perl TK resize window

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perltk

Is it possible to automatically resize a Tk window to the width and height of the text inside of the text plot?

Comment: Tell us more about the text. Is it a single line? Do you want to resize it so all the text fits in a single line? Even better, upload an image to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) with the window your code is drawing and a sketch of how you'd *like* it to look.

Comment: Basically the script outputs the disk size of all directories in C:\. I would like the window's width and height to automatically resize to the correct width and height of the text plot (so all the text width and height-wise fits on the screen without scrolling).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily measure how wide some text is in a particular font:

```
$font = $widget->Font(....);              # Get the font however you want
$lineWidth = $font->measure($text);       # Do this for each line; take the max
$lineHeight = $font->metrics(-linespace); # Get the height of a line; x # lines
```

Add in a bit of slop for borders, etc., and use this to set the size of the toplevel:

```
$toplevel->configure(-width=>$width, -height=>$height);
```

If it's not a toplevel that you want to control, it's easiest to do this by putting the contents in a frame and controlling the size of that frame (same method, same options). Also be aware that if you have too many rows or too long lines, it won't fit on the screen anyway.